# Probabilities in infinite Bernoulli type of series

Tags: probability, combinatorics

While I was trying to solve the 1st problem from [here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs109/pdfs/32%20ProblemSet5.pdf) I run into the following problem: find the probability of the events such as $1122213$ or $2122111116$ in infinite series of dice rolls which end on $\geq 3$ roll. The thing that the length of such series is not limited confuses my intuition a lot. How does one think about such problems. Is there a good book or article where I can find math that is relevant to such problems? I'm not interested in solving the original problem from the link, but finding the probabilities of aforementioned events.

Answer (score 0):

The probability to roll a number $\ge3$ is $\frac23$. Thus the expected number of rolls is $\frac32$, of which exactly one will be $\ge3$ and thus an expected number of $\frac12$ will be $\lt3$. Then by linearity of expectation, the expected total is

$$
\frac12\cdot\frac{1+2}2+1\cdot\frac{3+6}2=\frac{21}4\;.
$$

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but my question was more on how to calculate the probabilities for the events described in the question, not the solving the problem.

Comment: @hovo: Well, you should edit the question then. It very clearly says "I am trying to solve the 1st problem". Also, in that case you're going to have to say more about what exactly you mean by "events such as ...".

Comment: Done. The events are the series that end on 3,4,5,6.

Comment: @hovo: Unfortunately it's not any clearer to me what you're asking. The probability of obtaining a series that ends in $3,4,5,6$ is clearly $1$. Did you perhaps intend to ask for the probability that this series contains a certain number of rolls?

Comment: for example, what are the probabilities for $114$ or $12223$?

Comment: @hovo: I think you're barking up the wrong tree there. Those probabilities are simply $\left(\frac16\right)^3$ and $\left(\frac16\right)^5$, respectively, just like the probability of any other specific outcome of $n$ rolls is $\left(\frac16\right)^n$; that's not going to get you terribly far in solving the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42530/discussion-between-hovo-and-joriki).

Answer (score 0):

You can gain some intuition, if you are familiar with this problem:

A 2-dimensional plane is given. what is the probability of hitting a point on the plane. It is zero. But you can have non-zero probabilities by considering a region in the plane.

The same is applied to this problem. an infinite sequence happens with zero probability, while a limited sequence has a non-zero probability. So, for the first case, you may assume that the rest of the sequence exists, but it can have all the possibilities.

Hope it helps.